# How to install latest Gnome Calendar on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, calendar

I use 16.04 with standard Unity Desktop. How can I install the latest Gnome Calendar on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I want to keep the system solid and stable, so I don't favour to compile the latest Gnome sources by myself and stuff. So, I do have Gnome Calendar installed by the system, but it's obviously an old version.

I read [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released-new-features), that the latest Gnome couldn't be installed with 16.04. However, could Calendar possibly be installed separately from the whole Gnome environment?

Comment: Have you tried to find your app in the Gnome app store?

Comment: I didn't know that there was a Gnome app store? If you refer to the Ubuntu Software app, yes, I had a look there. Of course, all I could find there was the outdated version of Gnome Calendar, which ships with 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Try the one from Zesty, (17.04) on the page below. 17.04 isn't that different from 16.04, just not a long term release. You'll probably not want to add the repository, which would try to update every other program as well, so you'll probably want to download the .deb package and install with something like Gdebi package installer. It will check for dependencies and/or conflicts and won't install if those can't be resolved. I've done this with other programs. 
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/zesty/main/updates/gnome-calendar