# Installing Gnome-Calendar 3.28.0

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04

Just install Calendar 3.20.4 found  don’t have recurring events, I see there is a new version 3.28.0
and has  recurring events how to install this version on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/898793/how-to-install-latest-gnome-calendar-on-16-04

Comment: on 16.04, the current version is 3.20.4, but the 3.28 is able on 18.04, and i'm not sure that package of 18.04 are totally compatible with 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Gnome Calendar on 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898793/how-to-install-latest-gnome-calendar-on-16-04)